# CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

Guys any help I can get here I will appreciate it. I keep getting this error message not sure what's going on. "both Cell type numeric and string cannot be resolved"

```
          while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
                  final Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cellIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                newStudent.studentId = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                cellIndex++;
                            }
                            break;
                            
                        case 1:
                            if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                newStudent.major = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                cellIndex++;
                            }else {
                                newStudent.major = null;
                            }
                            break;
                            
                        case 2:
                            if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                newStudent.gender = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                cellIndex++;
                            }else {
                                newStudent.gender = null;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
```

Use these:

```
CellType.STRING
CellType.NUMERIC
```

Reference link is [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html)

Comment: wow that's actually it... Thanks

Comment: @papa, please do not forget to choose your accepted answer.  click buttons of appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually familiar with Apache POI, but from the documentation [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html), it looks like you might need to get `CellType.NUMERIC` instead of `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`, and `CellType.STRING` instead of `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING`?